# Running php multithreaded(using pthread) script from wamp-server localhost

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, wamp

I am trying to execute a multithreaded php script using php pthreads on Windows.

I have followed the following links, and placed the following files

pthreadVC2.dll

php_pthreads.dll

as suggested by the following links

http://emrahmehmedov.blogspot.com/2013/03/php-and-multi-thread-on-windows.html

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Also I have made changes to the php.ini file, as suggested.

The problem is :

The script is executed well when run using 'php' command using windows commandline, but when I try to run it from wamp-server localhost(wamp/www/) from the browser , it gives error "Thread Class not found". Here is my testing script:

```
    <?php
 class AsyncOperation extends Thread {
  public function __construct($arg){
   $this->arg = $arg;
  }

  public function run(){
   if($this->arg){
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
     echo "-> " . $this->arg . "\n";
     sleep(1);
    }
   }
  }
 }

 flush();
 $thread = new AsyncOperation("Thread 1");
 $thread2 = new AsyncOperation("Thread 2");
 $thread->start();
 $thread2->start();
 $thread->join();
 $thread2->join();
?>
```

Any Idea Why is this happening?? Any Solution for this?? as I have to run the script from the wamp-server localhost through browser. Please Help.

I have also enable php_pthreads extension form wamp GUI.

Please Help I have been struck here for 2 weeks.

Comment: Hi :) I am krakjoe. I do not use windows, so I cannot give you the answer. However, come into stackoverflow chat rooms and ping me, arrange for me to be able to control your computer remotely and I'll fix it for you ... I hate that you have been stuck for two weeks, if I knew what to do i'd tell you, I can definitely find out ... then I'd be able to tell people asking the same question what to do ... I don't know what else to suggest, it's not normally a good idea to give access to your computer to strangers ... but like I said, I am krakjoe ...

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem in Linux(Ubuntu). Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything to run pthread in wamp and no luck. I gave up and downloaded xampp and it took few minutes to run pthread